# Special CSS3 Circle with cutted top and bottom

Tags: css, geometry

I was wondering if it is posible to create a circle in CSS3, and then cut a bit of the top and bottom?

Like this:
[image]

Could be great if someone could help me out, with this :D

- TheYaXxE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a way. What you'll need to do is create a container div, and then have the circle inside it. Make the container smaller than the circle, and hide the overflow. Here's a JS fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/CrD3q/1/

CSS:

```
.circle {
    position: relative;
    top: -6px;
    width: 108px;
    height: 108px;
    background: blue;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

.container{
    height: 96px;
    width: 108px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

That should get you started, now fiddle with it to your needs!